# How do you get the selected items in a Wicket ListMultipleChoice?

Tags: wicket

I'm using a ListMultipleChoice component in wicket and I want to get the selected items.  It seems that isSelected is protected so I cannot use it.  How do I get the selected items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must bind your list with data and ListMultipleChoice as in [Example](http://www.jroller.com/dashorst/entry/wicket_reference_manual)

```java
public MyForm(String id, IModel model, IFeedback feedback) {
    List choices = new ArrayList();
    choices.add("foo");
    choices.add("bar");
    MultiListChoice lc = new MultiListChoice("myMultiListChoice", new PropertyModel(model, "foobarList"), choices);
    add(lc);
    ...
}
```